# If $f$ is integrable and $\exists D\subset A$ a dense set such that, $\forall x\in D$ $f(x)=0$ prove that $\int_A f=0$

Tags: calculus

$f:A\subset\mathbb{R^n}$, A a rectangle. I'm stuck, I wanted to use that if $f=0$ except in a set of measure zero, then $\int_A f=0$, but I'm not sure how to make that happen. I guess I have to use intA

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ? What's the connection between the title and the question ? **Hint** Prove that $\int_Nf=0$ for nul-set $N$, and then use the fact that $A=\{f=0\}\cup\{f\neq 0\}$.

Comment: By integrable do you mean Riemann integrable?

Comment: Yes, Riemann integrable @RRL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a partition $P$ such that the difference of upper and lower sums satisfies $U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon$. Using the density of $D$ it follows that for any partition $P$, we have $L(P,f) \leqslant 0 \leqslant U(P,f)$.

I leave it to you to show using these inequalities  that $\underline{\int}_Af = \overline{\int}_A f = \int_Af = 0.$

Comment: Thank you, could you explain me or where can I find that due to the density, it follows that for any partition P, we have $L(P,f)\leq 0\leq U(P,f)$

Comment: Every subrectangle $R$ in the partition must contain a point in $D$ where $f(x) = 0$.  Hence, $\inf_{x \in R} f(x) \leqslant 0 \leqslant \sup_{x \in R} f(x)$.  Multiplying by $vol(r)$ and summing we get $L(P,f) \leqslant 0 \leqslant U(P,f)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!